# What approach is recommended for defining important startup processes? (Independent of shell)

Tags: shell, docker, sysvinit

#### Note on formatting

I've gone back and added bold text to my specific questions, because I feel the details have lead to the question getting lost. However, the details are kind of necessary to understand why the simplest solution isn't necessarily going to work.

## Background

Asked a question like this recently on StackOverflow and they didn't take kindly to it since it wasn't strictly about programming. My company is in the midst of a major shift to the cloud and using Docker instead of building everything locally. In general, this is good, but we're trying to do things Right™. Toward that goal, I've learned a good many things about the depths of Unix/Linux and how it works, but I don't necessarily understand when one approach is preferable to another.

#### Edit

After the great info from Marcus, I realized I needed to add a bit more context. So, we use GitLab CI/CD for deploying code to the cloud. The design of the pipeline is not left to the individual repositories, because we have high security requirements, and can't allow the possibility that someone skips out on security scans, or other actions of that nature. To give us this level of control, we've made the pipeline an external repository, and then that pipeline has extension points that can be hooked into by other pipeline projects (promoted to the main pipeline via merge request).

The pipeline extensions are two parts: a YAML configuration, and a Docker image. To keep the YAML short and simple, we have taken the approach of putting all logic for the specific pipeline stage into the container that it runs on. The early days of doing this saw a lot of moving scripts into a directory like `/usr/local/bin`. However, it still led to some clunky implementations, like the following command:

```bash
docker compose up
timeout $SERVICE_READY_TIMEOUT sh -c \
    "until curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail $SERVICE_READY_ENDPOINT; do \
        sleep 1; \
    done"
# run the integration test after service is ready
```

Instead, I added a script to `/etc/profile.d` that reads as the following:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

## Define functions to be loaded into the shell environment
pollUrl() {
  endpoint="$1"

  until curl --output /dev/null --silent --fail "$endpoint"; do 
    sleep 1; 
  done
}

waitForLive() {
  max_duration=$1
  endpoint="$2"

  timeout $max_duration sh -c "pollUrl '$endpoint'"
}
```

Another specific problem I'm trying to solve is storing an environment variable in one stage for use in another stage. Yes, the simplest solution would be to copy it to both places. The problem is that it is two separate builds. The variable I'm capturing is provided in the build of my Docker image, but it is being used later in the actual pipeline extension. My current approach has me writing it to `/etc/profile.d` as well.

But then we get back to the original problem: **how do you define `ENV` for the user so that their profile gets loaded?**

## Question

**In terms of things that happen when launching a shell, when is `/etc/init.d` preferred, versus `/etc/profile.d`, and how do I define `$ENV` so that the correct profile is loaded initially? More to the point, what types of things go where?** Examples: functions to be loaded into the shell for re-use, environment variables for configuring tools like NPM/Yarn, and especially things like `$ENV` which determine how your shell starts up to begin with.

If there's a formal document describing these things, that would be immensely helpful, since I'm relatively new to Linux as a whole. I've already downloaded the Linux Documentation Project (PDF), and frequent the various Linux Man Page sites out there, but most sources skew toward Bash which isn't always an option for me.

### Updated Question

So, therein lies my reasoning for asking these questions. **What is a POSIX-compliant approach to defining functions and environment variables in the Shell that isn't specific to the shell in question (Bash, ZSH, etc.), and what guidance can you give on making the judgement call of when it should be in one system vs another?**

## Additional Information

I know that some shells, like ZSH and Bash, provide a run command file `.<name>rc`, as well as other conventions like `.<name>_profile` or just `.profile`. These conventions are either specific to that shell, or otherwise not universally read. That brought me to the understanding that setting `ENV=/etc/profile` in my Dockerfile will load anything in the `/etc/profile.d` directory that ends in `*.sh` and is executable by the current user. However, in my WSL environment where I'm able to customize it to my liking, I can't pre-load the `ENV` value before I drop into the shell, specifically when I try to use `/bin/sh` for testing my script compatibility across platforms (we have Mac users that use ZSH so my Bash scripts frequently break on their side).

Answer (score 0):

> In terms of things that happen when launching a shell, when is /etc/init.d preferred, versus /etc/profile.d

They do completely different things.

profile.d contains scripts sourced by a shell to set up common environments; init.d contained (under sys V) scripts, launched by a boot controlling program, to start, stop, restart or reload the configuration of services, depending on the arguments passed to these scripts.

Note that if your company is moving to cloud right now, typical distros for cloud VMs (OpenSUSE, Alma Linux/Rocky Linux/Oracle Linux/Red Hat Enterprise Linux, or Ubuntu) do *not* use Sys V. (they support it through an emulation layer.)

These distros actually take advantage of the finer-grained control, parallelism and resilience features of systemd.

Other cloud-typical deployments are based on starting singular services in containers, and hence typically *also* not depend on sysvinit in these containers.

So, the question really is why you're reading into sysvinit in 2024 when considering cloud services.

> Examples: functions to be loaded into the shell for re-use, environment variables for configuring tools like NPM/Yarn, and especially things like $ENV which determine how your shell starts up to begin with.

These are all development/usage things, and don't sound like things you want to do on a cloud server. You put the environment variables a specific service needs to function typically in the service file (in the systemd case). For sys v init scripts, admins used to modify these. There's little sense changing how *all* possible apache http servers (just an example) start, when you want to modify only one, and want to avoid unforeseen side effects.

Generally, I personally consider systemd service files the much cleaner approach, adopted for good reasons across the board for Linux systems that control services upstarts. A very small but verbal community of users thinks systemd is evil. OK.

> However, in my WSL environment where I'm able to customize it to my liking, I can't pre-load the ENV value before I drop into the shell, specifically when I try to use /bin/sh for testing my script compatibility across platforms (we have Mac users that use ZSH so my Bash scripts frequently break on their side).

That's all local on your machine. Put your configuration of *your* personal shell in your personal ~/.zshrc.

Comment: You provided some good info, but I think I failed to convey some of the architecture. As a company, we restrict a lot of things because security is paramount. As such, we need to make sure all code goes through security scans, among other things. As such, we have various stages the build process goes through. One part is that all parts of the pipeline (using GitLab CI/CD) have Docker images tailored to their use, but the pipeline stages themselves are mostly devoid of code, calling things present in the container. Ex: my automated testing container has a global `integration-test` script

Comment: that sounds pretty reasonable and typical!

Comment: I updated my question with the added detail, but I'm still wondering where I should define things like the initialization of `ENV` that sets what gets run when starting the shell (such as `/etc/profile`), but then also where I should be defining things like functions to be used (such as the `waitForUrl` function in my updated question)?

Comment: no, as said, don't put things into /etc/profile that affect individual service instantiations. That makes no sense; these things are for interactive/login shells